# FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification with network printer fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (called from service)

Tags: windows, printing, network-printers

I want to monitor print jobs on remote (shared) printers from service. I have impersonation access token for user who connects printer (e.g. \PC-PRINTER\Canon Printer).

After impersonation as the user I call OpenPrinter to printer and then FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification. OpenPrinter succeeded but FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification failed with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE error.

If I try it as normal user (owner of printer - not a service), all succeeded and notification are functional. Also if I try it on Windows XP it succeeded, it fails only on Windows 7 and probably Windows Vista.

I suppose that I have to set some security attributes for impersonation token or pass some other attributes to OpenPrinter. I have tried many things, but I didn't find solution.

My code example:

```
PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE optionsType;
unsigned short jobFields[] = {JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PRINTER_NAME};
optionsType.Type = JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE;
optionsType.Count = 1;
optionsType.pFields = &jobFields[0];

PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS options;
options.Version = 2; 
options.Count = 1;
options.pTypes = &optionsType;
options.Flags = 0;

DWORD dwFilter = PRINTER_CHANGE_DELETE_JOB | PRINTER_CHANGE_SET_JOB ;
HANDLE hPrinterHandle = NULL;

ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hUserToken); //I retrieve token from printer owner's process (I try every process for this user)

OpenPrinter(L"\\\\PC-PRINTER\\Canon Printer", &hPrinterHandle, NULL); \\it succeeded and I try many other parameters as well

HANDLE hNotification = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(hPrinterHandle, dwFilter, 0, (LPVOID) &options);

if (hNotification == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{//it comes here, GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (Windows 7, process runs as service)
 //it succeded on Windows XP or when process runs in printer owner context
}

RevertToSelf();
```

Thanks for any solution!